# How to fail promise in Scala

Tags: scala, promise, future

In Scala documentation, there is an example how to pick future which succeeds faster by using promises.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#promises

```
def first[T](f: Future[T], g: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val p = promise[T]
  f onSuccess {
    case x => p.trySuccess(x)
  }
  g onSuccess {
    case x => p.trySuccess(x)
  }
  p.future
}
```

This function returns the future which succeeds first and if either one of them fails, it never completes.

Is it possible to modify this in a way that even if other future fails, then the second is returned if it's successful and if both of them are successful, then the faster one is picked like the code does now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this:

```
f onFailure {
  case e =>
    g onFailure {
      case _ =>
        p.failure(e)
    }
}
```

When both futures are failed, this will fail the promise with the same exception as `f`. You can elaborate on this to create an exception that records the 2 exceptions coming from `f` and `g` if necessary.

Comment: Don't use exceptions, uses `Either` monad instead.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin using an `Either` here is silly because a future already encapsulates an `Either` by having success and failure states. Using an Either is just reinventing the wheel in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to follow the advice of Alvin Alexander for futures and promises in Scala [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-future-semantics)

I believe that this is the best way to work with futures

```
package futures

import scala.concurrent.{Future => ConcurrentTask}           // rename
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import Utils.sleep

object FutureAsConcurrentTask extends App {

  // run some long-running task (task has type Future[Int] in this example)
  val task = ConcurrentTask {
    Cloud.executeLongRunningTask
  }

  // whenever the task completes, execute this code
  task.onComplete {
    case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback, value = $value")
    case Failure(e) => println(s"D'oh! The task failed: ${e.getMessage}")
  }

  // do your other work
  println("A ..."); sleep(100)
  println("B ..."); sleep(100)
  println("C ..."); sleep(100)
  println("D ..."); sleep(100)
  println("E ..."); sleep(100)
  println("F ..."); sleep(100)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic pattern for picking the fastest future or timing out if they all are too slow:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }
import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern.after

object GetFastestFutureOrTimeout extends App {
  val e = new TimeoutException("TimeoutException")
  val system = ActorSystem("GetFastestFutureOrTimeout")
  val f1 = Future { Thread.sleep(200); "this is f1" }
  val f2 = Future { Thread.sleep(100); "this is f2" }
  val timeoutFuture = after(500.milliseconds, using = system.scheduler) { Future.failed(e) }
  val f = Future.firstCompletedOf(f1 :: f2 :: timeoutFuture :: Nil)

  f onComplete {
    case Success(msg) => println(msg)
    case Failure(err) => println("An error occured: " + err.getMessage)
  }
}
```

This prints "this is f2".  If the timeout of timeoutFuture were changed to 50, it would print "An error occured: TimeoutException".

Under the hood firstCompletedOf uses a Promise to return the value of the first Future that is completed, see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L503.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a basic implementation to pick up the fastest successful response or fail if they all failed:

```
def getFirstSuccessfulResultOrFail[T](requests: List[Future[T]]): Future[T] = {
  val p              = Promise[T]()
  val countDownLatch = AtomicInt(0)

  requests.foreach { f =>
    f.onComplete {
      case Failure(e) => if (countDownLatch.addAndGet(1) == requests.size) p.tryFailure(e)
      case Success(s) => p.trySuccess(s)
    }
  }

  p.future
}
```